# How to sync rhythmbox playlists to device with relative path?

Tags: rhythmbox

I am trying to sync an external usb device with Rhythmbox. In the device properties I select the playlists I want to sync and it copies Music + Playlists correctly to the device. However, the paths in the playlists copied to the device seem to be absolute, not relative, which renders the playlists unusable. They look like this:

```
file:///media/neferty/9016-4EF8/Music/...
```

My .is_audio_player file looks like this:

```
name="Clip Zip 16GB SSD"
audio_folders=Music/
output_formats=audio/mpeg,audio/x-ms-wma,application/ogg
playlist_formats=audio/x-mpegurl,audio/mpeg-url
playlist_path=Playlists/

endoffile=PlaceThisHereToEnsureThereIsABlankSpaceBeforeTheLastLineOfTheFile
```

Does anyone know how to make Rhythmbox to save playlists with relative path?